# Svelte - How Component one can use functions from Component two?

Tags: components, svelte

How can CompOne run the function "test" in CompTwo?

**CompOne.svelte**

```
<script>
   import {test} from './CompTwo.svelte'
</script>
<!-- Some style and HTML tags for this component -->
```

**CompTwo.svelte**

```
<script>
   export const test = () => { console.log('testing function') }
</script>
<!-- Some style and HTML tags for this component -->
```

Comment: You can use <script context="module"> to make exports possible. But I think you are looking fot something like this. By the was: was one of my first questions too. More here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57994637/what-is-the-best-way-to-signal-50-nested-components-to-execute-a-child-componen

Answer (score 13):

You can run children's functions if you have an instance of this component and bind to it.

**App.svelte**

```
<script>
  import Component from './Component.svelte';   
  let comp;
</script>

<Component bind:this={comp} />
<button on:click={() => comp.test()}>Do Stuff</button>
```

**Component.svelte**

```
<script>
    export const test = () => console.log('testing');
</script>
```

[Working example](https://svelte.dev/repl/3b6d095ff117430998e1a2b7b5f98857?version=3.12.1)

Comment: [Working REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/3b6d095ff117430998e1a2b7b5f98857?version=3.12.1). @Stephane, please add it to your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem, but I just might found a workaround.

In the child component you can declare

```
<ChildComponent>
  <script>
    export const myFunc = () => alert('alarm... alarm..');
  </script>
</ChildComponent>

<RootComponent>
  <script>
    import ChildComponent from './ChildComponent.svelte';
    let myFunc;
  </script>

  <ChildComponent bind:myFunc={myFunc} />
  <button on:click={myFunc} >Testing Alarm</button>
</RootComponent>
```

See working example here:
[Example Svelte - Executing function on child component workaround](https://svelte.dev/repl/47c6503a88cb4c5cbe947ceb0164d956?version=3.21.0)

Comment: Please don't give offsite links as answers, as they may become stale in the future. Include relevant code on your answer (or question) as needed.

Comment: @Dragonthoughts Especially svelte REPLs, I've never found one that works and is older than a year.

Answer (score 0):

U can use custom event in svelte
Here is the link for it : https://svelte.dev/tutorial/component-events

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34530418)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `<script context="module">` to export functions, since the default export of a svelte file is the component itself.

If the functions deal with data used on the page, you can use a svelte store:

`import { get, writable } from 'svelte/store';`

and then create a writable:

`let myStore = writable('defaultValue');`

You can set the value with `myStore.set()` and update it with `myStore.update()` which takes in a function that provides the current value and returns the new one. You can use a store inside the component with `$myStore` to subscribe to updates.